# Discord jda bot || UserUpdateActivitiesEvent does not trigger

Tags: java, listener, discord-jda

I tried tracking if people on the bots guild change activities (like starting to play a game)

After reading the javadoc I found out:

- GatewayIntent.GUILD_PRESENCES
- CacheFlag.ACTIVITY
- MemberCachePolicy.ONLINE (therefore GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS)

must be active.

so thats my Main:

```
        JDABuilder builder = JDABuilder.createDefault(token);
        builder.enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_PRESENCES);
        builder.enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS);
        builder.enableCache(CacheFlag.ACTIVITY);
        builder.setMemberCachePolicy(MemberCachePolicy.ONLINE);
        builder.setChunkingFilter(ChunkingFilter.ALL);
        this.jda = builder.build();
        jda.addEventListener( new ActivityListener(jda));
```

And this my Listener:

```
public class ActivityListener extends ListenerAdapter {
    private final JDA jda;

    public ActivityListener(JDA jda) {
        this.jda = jda;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUserUpdateActivities(@NotNull UserUpdateActivitiesEvent event) {
        super.onUserUpdateActivities(event);
        System.out.println(event.getUser().getAsTag() + " " + event.getUser().getIdLong());
    }
}
```

Sadly when I or someone else starts a game or smt else it never triggers.

Edit:
I used jda.getUserCache(); to check if the caching worked and I am i the cache, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps maybe put `jda.addEventListener(new ActivityListener(jda));` before the `this.jda = builder.build()`?

Comment: I added some other listeners in the class, to test it and they worked so I dont think that wont change smth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The members for the associated users have to be cached *before* the event fires. Since you use lazy loading this might take a while to happen since members are added to cache through messages or voice states.

You can use [setChunkingFilter(ChunkingFilter.ALL)](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDABuilder.html#setChunkingFilter(net.dv8tion.jda.api.utils.ChunkingFilter)) to eagerly load all members on startup.

---

There was a bug which caused these events to not fire which has been fixed in **4.2.1_264**.

Comment: Thank you, I added that and sadly still nothing happens.

Comment: @Dude2345 can you try updating JDA to 4.2.1_264? I think there was a bug that caused the events to not fire properly.

Answer (score 1):

the UserUpdateActivitiesEvent requires the GuildPresence intent to be enabled. You enabled it in your code, but it has to also be enabled on the discord api website at https://discord.com/developers/applications -> Your Application -> Bot -> Enable Presence Intent